# Add/Remove element-binding in Bindinghandler - knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hello I have created a list and sliced it up and added pagingnation.
All works good but I would like the user to be able to disable pagingnation and just use regular scroll.

My html mark-up looks somewhat like this atm.

```
<div data-bind="event: { mousewheel: ScrolledPagingnation }">
</div>
```

Im thinking a custom handler is the right tool for the job? but havent really have any succes adding/removing the event..

```
<div data-bind="toggleScroll: EnablePagingnation">
</div>
```

EnablePagingnation is just an observable toggeling a boolen.
How can I implement adding/removing of the 'event object on my element?
Any other suitable approach is welcome aswell.. :)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.toggleScroll = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {

        var value = valueAccessor();

         if (ko.unwrap(value) === true) {
             //Pseudo Code
             element add "event: { mousewheel: ScrolledPagination }"


         } else {
              //Clean the Binding
              ko.cleanNode(element);
         }
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `cleanNode`. Ever.

You don't even need a bindingHandler. Just use an expression for the event handler. I used the click event in the snippet below.

```js
vm = {
  active: ko.observable(false),
  v: ko.observable(1),
  addToV: function() {
    vm.v(vm.v() + 1);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
#area {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="area" data-bind="event: {click: active() ? addToV : null}"></div>
Activate:
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: active" />
<div data-bind="text: v"></div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Just to translate it for the question, it will become `event: { mousewheel: enablePagination() ? scrolledPagination : null }`

Comment: Perfect thx - I kind a thought there would be a solution like this.. Had been fiddeling around with enable/disable binding without any luck and came to the conclusion i needed a handler..
This is better. Cheers :)